# Why does setting CYGWIN=winsymlinks:nativestrict break zsh's (oh-my-zsh) history?

Tags: cygwin, zsh, symbolic-link, history, oh-my-zsh

I have this in my .zshrc

```
CYGWIN=winsymlinks:nativestrict
```

When I source .zshrc or start the terminal. I get this error:

```
zsh: locking failed for /home/r892107/.zsh_history: no such file or directory: reading anyway
```

although the file exists and I am its owner

```
> ls -la $HISTFILE
-rw------- 1 user users 595 Jun 29 15:48 /home/user/.zsh_history
> echo $HISTFILE&& echo $HISTSIZE && echo $SAVEHIST
/home/user/.zsh_history
10000
10000
```

New commands are not added anymore to the history file.
When I remove the CYGWIN variable, history works again.

Comment: Switching from `nativestrict` to just `native` worked for me.

Comment: I had a similar problem: `zsh: locking failed for /home/pablo/.zsh/history: no such file or directory`. I couldn't find a more elegant solution than just `mkdir .zsh` (of course on `$HOME` folder.